# jQuery: add callback function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

So I have this function

```
$.fn.myFunction = function( options, callback ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        opacity     : '',
        margin  : ''
    }, options );
}
```

and I do some funny stuff like this

```
$('.selector').myFunction( options, function() { /* do some stuff */ } );
```

Where should I specify inside my function about the callback function and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

JS

```
$.fn.myFunction = function( options , callback ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        opacity     : '',
        margin  : ''
    }, options );

    // where you want your callback
    if(callback && typeof callback === "function") callback();
}
```

Comment: It's weird because it works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/2ua11u6y/ Can you send a jsfiddle to show your problem ? Thanks

Comment: You can also add your `callback` as a method of your `options` object and invoke it like this `if(options.callback && typeof options.callback === "function") options.callback();`

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed, I had to put the callback() inside the .onComplete() of another function.

Answer (score 1):

A callback is simply a parameter in a function. So, your case could be expressed very simply:

```
var myFunction = function(options, callback) {
    console.log('I am running in the main function');
    if (callback) { callback(); }
};

myFunction('', function() {
    console.log('I am running in the callback!');
});
```

Demo is here: http://repl.it/0b0